# Are devices removed and later added again counted towards the max device number in iOS Provisioning Portal?

Tags: iphone, app-store, provisioning, iphone-developer-program, ios-provisioning

The maximum number of 100 registered devices per year in the iOS Provisioning Portal is a tough limit, especially since the introduction of the iPad and iPhone 4. There's a certain number of devices in our group of beta testers that can probably deleted - BUT there's a slight chance, these devices will be needed again.

Now my questions is, will a removed device counted as a new device if it's added again later on?

Bonus question: When will the the limit of 100 devices per year be freed from the removed devices? When renewing the iOS developer agreement or at the end of the calendar year? (To me, it looks like the prior, but both dates are close together in our case, so I can't tell exactly.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Now my questions is, will a removed
>   device counted as a new device if it's
>   added again later on?

Unfortunately, yes.

> Bonus question: When will the the
>   limit of 100 devices per year be freed
>   from the removed devices? When
>   renewing the iOS developer agreement
>   or at the end of the calendar year?

You will be able to register 100 new devices exactly after one year. Even if you renewed your agreement earlier.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean with "after one year"? Let's say I started the developer agreement on November 1, will the removed devices be "credited" on November 2 or on January 1? Or does it even depend on when I added the device initially?

Comment: They will be credited on November 2. Even if you renewed your agreement earlier (like September or October).

Comment: Henrik, can you point us to the link where this has been mentioned officially by Apple.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Henrik's answer, there's a special mode in the provisioning portal when the account is renewed and no new device has been added again yet:[image: Reset mode in iOS provisioning portal]

Comment: Note that second part: *After* you add a device, any deletions do not free up a slot until the next year's renewal. So delete all unwanted devices *before* adding any device. In other words, adding a device starts the 100-limit counter.